# Previewing changes to a Google Gadget with preferences

Tags: blogger, google-gadget

I just finished building a [map for my Blogger.com blog](http://www.fiveyearsabroad.com/p/map.html).  Now I'd like to convert it into a Gadget so that I can move it into the sidebar on my blog's design and share it with other bloggers.

Is there a strategy I can employ to test my gadget during development — preferably something that will let me make some changes, then refresh the page in my browser to test them?

Adding the gadget to a sandbox blog doesn't work; it seems like the XML file is cached, so I have to wait to preview changes (or keep changing the name of the URL to the XML file, but that gets irritating real quick).

I've added the [Google Gadgets Editor](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/tools#GGE) to my iGoogle homepage so that I can preview the Gadget, and that almost works... except I can't specify values for my Gadget's preferences in GGE's preview panel, so it won't render.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
 ?nogadgetcache=1
```

When you load your gadget ?